# Not able to create dynamic instance of flash object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic, multiple-instances

Ok so i'm trying to display multiple instance of an object square(movie clip) on different location on screen.

```
var k1=0,k=0,p=0;
for (k1=0;k1<5;k1++)
{

drawrect(k,p);
k=k+101;

}
```

This above code is for number of times i want to display the object om screen horizontally in line.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

function drawrect(x1:Number,y1:Number){
    // statements here
    trace("Hello world!");
var MC_squre:MovieClip= new MovieClip();
MC_squre.x=x1;
MC_squre.y=y1;

addChild(MC_squre);

};
```

this Function is trying to declare instance of movieclip SQUARE and place it at given parameter in function.i might want to make it and array of the instance later too.i tried this code with just

```
var square:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(square);
square.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x000000);
square.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
square.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
square.graphics.endFill();
```

and it worked but i want to now use it by library object not just on drawn shapes.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: You want to create Class extending Sprite (with code drawing rectangle), right? If so, read about ActionScript Linkage then correct question.

Comment: Konard is right. See Library->Linkage if you have Flash.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to make your object in the library accessible by actionscript.
To do that, go into the properties of that Clip, click on "Advanced", and check the box "Export for Actionscript".
When pressing "Ok", you will get a warning that such a class does not exist and it will be automatically generated. That is ok.

Whatever you put as a classname in the Properties, you then have to use to instanciate your objects. If it is for example MySquare, use that.
So your above code would look like this:

```
 function drawrect(x1:Number,y1:Number){
    // statements here
    trace("Hello world!");
    var MC_squre:MovieClip= new MySquare();
    MC_squre.x=x1;
    MC_squre.y=y1;

    addChild(MC_squre);
};
```